# Python Selenium -> Check whether Firefox 32/64bit or Chrome 32/64bit installed?

Tags: python, x86, pyinstaller, 32bit-64bit

I have coded a python skript using a 32bit geckodriver.exe.
I package this script with the geckodriver included as an Pyinstalled .exe file.

I recognized, this .exe doesn't run when somebody uses Firefox 64bit.
And obviously it doesn't either work when somebody doesnt use Firefox at all, but Chrome instead.

So theoretically, yes I can package 2 geckodriver versions (32/64) and 2 chromedriver versions (32/64) into the .exe, but HOW can I find out which browser and which version (32/64) is installed on the system of the user?

It's only windows-system... so is there a way by reading the users registry or so?
Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with the registry as this:

```py
from winreg import HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
import winreg
try:
    winreg.OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe', 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS).Close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Chrome not installed')
```

And same for firefox

here is a good way to use it in function:

```py
import os
import win32file
from winreg import *
import winreg
CHROME_KEY = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe'
def is_chrome_installed():
    try:
        key = winreg.OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, CHROME_KEY, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        path_dir = QueryValueEx(key, "PATH")[0]
        file_arc = win32file.GetBinaryType(os.path.join(path_dir, 'chrome.exe'))
        if file_arc == 0:
            print('its a 32bit')
        elif file_arc == 6:
            print('its a 64bit')
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Chrome not installed')
        return False
```

notice that you need to be run as administartor for this to work

Comment: Do you think there is a way without administrator rights? And what about checking 32/64bit?

Comment: @tim do you want to know if the whole system is 32 or 64 or the chrome specificly, and about the administator is to read registry, i think you must have admin premissions for this

Comment: Just mean to check whether the installed browser is 32 or 64 bit version. Because afaik geckodriver is always a specific version or is there a geckodriver which supports both versions of Firefox?

Comment: @tim i updated my answer, now with a check for 32 or 64 :)